# MultiMap not Printing List

Tags: c++

I am having 2 issues with my code.

The 1st issue is that my multimap is not printing, and I don't know why.

The 2nd issue is that I don't know how to create a function to search and find a specific item in my multimap.

You can change as much of the code as you want, but I need to keep the class or change it to a struct.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string> 
#include<iterator>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

class SongNode {
public:
    string title;
    string artist;
    float rating;
};

//Constants
#define INFINITE_LOOP 1
#define LEFT_JUSTIFIED 30

//Prototypes

void sortByArtist(multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode); 
void sortByRating(multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode); 


//FUNCTION      : void sortByArtist
//PARAMETER     : multimap<string, SongNode>&newSongNode
//RETURN        : void
//DESCRIPTION   : This function will sort the multimap by the artist of the song
void sortByArtist(multimap<string, SongNode>&newSongNode) {
    multimap<string, SongNode>temp; 

    for (auto i = newSongNode.begin(); i != newSongNode.end(); i++) 
        temp.insert(pair<string, SongNode>(i->second.artist, i->second)); 
    newSongNode.clear(); 

    for (auto i = temp.begin(); i != temp.end(); i++)
        newSongNode.insert(pair<string, SongNode>(i->second.artist, i->second)); 
    temp.clear(); 
}

//FUNCTION      : void sortByRating
//PARAMETER     : (multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode
//RETURN        : void
//DESCRIPTION   : This function will sort the multimap by the rating. 
void sortByRating(multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode) {

    multimap<float, SongNode, greater<int>> temp; 

    for (auto i = newSongNode.begin(); i != newSongNode.end(); i++)
        temp.insert(pair<int, SongNode>(i->second.rating, i->second)); 
    newSongNode.clear(); 

    for (auto i = temp.begin(); i != temp.end(); i++)
        newSongNode.insert(pair<string, SongNode>(" ", i->second)); 
    temp.clear(); 
}
    
int main() {

    multimap<string, SongNode> songList; 
    multimap<string, SongNode>::iterator itr; 
    string title; 
    string artist; 
    int rating; 
    SongNode* newSongNode = new SongNode; 

    cout << "Please enter a title artist and rating\n"; 

    while (INFINITE_LOOP) {
        cout << "Title: "; 
        cin >> title;

        if (title == ".") {
            break; 
        }

        cout << "Artist: "; 
        cin >> artist; 

        cout << "Rating: ";
        cin >> rating; 

        //Error check  for rating 
        while (INFINITE_LOOP) {     

            if (rating < 1) {
                cout << "The rating you have entered is less then 1\n";
                cout << "Rating: ";
                cin >> rating;
                break;
            }

            else if (rating > 5) {
                cout << "The rating you have to enterd is greater then 5\n";
                cout << "Rating: ";
                cin >> rating;
                break; 
            }

            else
                break;
        }

        SongNode* newNode = new SongNode; 

        newNode->title = title;
        newNode->artist = artist; 
        newNode->rating = rating; 

        songList.insert(pair<string, SongNode>(title, *newSongNode));
    }

    //display the two lists here. 
    cout << "Artist Sorted List\n"; 
    sortByArtist(songList); 
    for (itr = songList.begin(); itr != songList.end(); ++itr) {
        cout << "Title" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << itr->second.title; 
        cout << "Artist" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << itr->second.artist; 
        cout << "Rating" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << itr->second.rating<<endl; 
    }

    cout << "\n"; 
    cout << "Rating Sorted List\n"; 
    sortByRating(songList); 

    delete newSongNode; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program step by step, one line at a time, and use your debugger to track the values of all variables and observe how they change after executing each line of your program, what did you see?

Comment: I don't think `delete songList; ` was in the code when you last ran it. That or `songList` was a pointer. I recommend fixing this up or you'll have people writing answers for the wrong bug.

Comment: `{ ... SongNode* newNode = new SongNode; ... songList.insert(pair<string, SongNode>(title, *newSongNode)); }` is a memory leak, as `newNode` is never destroyed.

Comment: "*I am having 2 issue with my code*" - then you should be posting 2 separate questions, one for each issue.

Comment: Why are you using `new` at all?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have two variables with similar names, and you definitely misuse them:

```cpp
    SongNode* newSongNode = new SongNode; 
    // ...
    SongNode* newNode = new SongNode; 
   
    newNode->title = title;
    newNode->artist = artist; 
    newNode->rating = rating; 

    songList.insert(pair<string, SongNode>(title, *newSongNode));
```

You are initializing the `newNode` but inserting the `newSongNode`. The values are initialized with empty strings, so that may explain no printing.

As for "searching in a multimap" be more specific in what your problem is.

Comment: "*As for "searching in a multimap" be more specific in what your problem is*" - it should be actually posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not populating the `songList` with the `SongNode` objects that you fill with data.  You have an extra `SongNode` that has no data in it, which is the only object you are putting into the `songList`.  So there is nothing to print.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

struct SongNode {
    string title;
    string artist;
    float rating;
};

//Constants
#define INFINITE_LOOP 1
#define LEFT_JUSTIFIED 30

//Prototypes

void sortByArtist(multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode); 
void sortByRating(multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode); 


//FUNCTION      : void sortByArtist
//PARAMETER     : multimap<string, SongNode>&newSongNode
//RETURN        : void
//DESCRIPTION   : This function will sort the multimap by the artist of the song
void sortByArtist(multimap<string, SongNode> &newSongNode) {
    multimap<string, SongNode> temp; 

    for (auto &elem : newSongNode) 
        temp.insert(make_pair(elem.second.artist, elem.second)); 
    newSongNode.clear(); 

    for (auto &elem : temp)
        newSongNode.insert(make_pair(elem.second.artist, elem.second)); 
}

//FUNCTION      : void sortByRating
//PARAMETER     : (multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode
//RETURN        : void
//DESCRIPTION   : This function will sort the multimap by the rating. 
void sortByRating(multimap<string, SongNode>& newSongNode) {

    multimap<float, SongNode, greater<int>> temp; 

    for (auto &elem : newSongNode)
        temp.insert(make_pair(elem.second.rating, elem.second)); 
    newSongNode.clear(); 

    for (auto &elem : temp)
        newSongNode.insert(make_pair(" ", elem.second)); 
}
    
int main() {

    multimap<string, SongNode> songList; 
    string title, artist;
    float rating; 

    cout << "Please enter a title artist and rating\n"; 

    while (INFINITE_LOOP) {
        cout << "Title: "; 
        cin >> title;

        if (title == ".") {
            break; 
        }

        cout << "Artist: "; 
        cin >> artist; 

        cout << "Rating: ";
        cin >> rating; 

        //Error check for rating
        while (INFINITE_LOOP) {     
            if (!cin) {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout << "The rating you have entered is invalid\n";
            }
            else if (rating < 1.0f) {
                cout << "The rating you have entered is less then 1\n";
            }
            else if (rating > 5.0f) {
                cout << "The rating you have to entered is greater then 5\n";
            }
            else
                break;

            cout << "Rating: ";
            cin >> rating;
        }

        SongNode newNode; 

        newNode.title = title;
        newNode.artist = artist; 
        newNode.rating = rating; 

        songList.insert(make_pair(title, newNode));
    }

    //display the two lists here. 

    cout << "Artist Sorted List\n"; 
    sortByArtist(songList); 
    for (auto &elem : songList) {
        cout << "Title" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << elem.second.title; 
        cout << "Artist" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << elem.second.artist; 
        cout << "Rating" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << elem.second.rating << endl; 
    }
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Rating Sorted List\n"; 
    sortByRating(songList); 
    for (auto &elem : songList) {
        cout << "Title" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << elem.second.title; 
        cout << "Artist" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << elem.second.artist; 
        cout << "Rating" << left << setw(LEFT_JUSTIFIED) << elem.second.rating << endl; 
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```